# Render UILabel to UIImage in much higher resolution

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using below function to render a UILabel to UIImage

```
func labelToImage(_ label: UILabel) -> UIImage {           
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: label.frame.size.width*10, height: label.frame.size.height*10), false, 0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return UIImage() }
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    label.layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? UIImage()
}
```

But the resolution of the resultant image is too low for my needs and I need it about 10 times higher. I do not want to scale the resultant image as that will pixelate it.

I want to scale the UILabel and then render it to image. I have tried `CGAffinTransform Scale` but that does not do anything.

Comment: Are you trying to scale the text as well as its frame? With your approach the label size won't change

Comment: Yes, I want to scale text in the label as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to scale the label’s frame and font size before drawing it into your new image context:

```
func labelToImage(_ label: UILabel) -> UIImage? {
    let size = label.frame.size.applying(.init(scaleX: 10, y: 10))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    label.frame.size = size
    label.font = label.font.withSize(label.font.pointSize * 10)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    label.draw(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

You can also extend UILabel to be able to scale it to a certain size or percentage:

```
extension UILabel {
    func scaledImage(to size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        let aspectRatio = size.width/frame.size.width
        frame = frame.applying(.init(scaleX: aspectRatio, y: aspectRatio))
        font = font.withSize(font.pointSize * aspectRatio)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
    func scaledImage(by percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        frame = frame.applying(.init(scaleX: percentage, y: percentage))
        font = font.withSize(font.pointSize * percentage)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(.init(origin: .zero, size: frame.size))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 30)))
label.text = "StackOverflow"
label.scaledImage(by: 10)
```

[image]